# Riemann Integral - partitions

Tags: real-analysis

> Give an example of a continuous and bounded function $f \colon [0,2]
>  \to \mathbb{R}$ and a sequence of partitions $\{P_{n}\}$ such that
> each $P_{n}$ is composed of $n$ subintervals and such that $\lim_{n
> \to \infty} U(f,P_{n}) $ exists but does not equal $\int_{0}^{2} f$.
> Choose your $f$ so that the integral is geometrically obvious as area.
> Explain why this doesn't contradict the Archimedes-Riemann Theorem.

How can this be true? From what I understand we are looking for a sequence of partitions $\{P_{n}\}$ such that as $n$ gets larger (as the norm of the partition $\to 0$) the $\lim_{n
\to \infty} U(f,P_{n}) $ exists but does not equal $\int_{0}^{2} f$. But this seems impossible: Our function is continuous so it is Riemann integrable so for any partition $\{P_{n}\}$ such that the norm of the partition $\to 0$ then that partition is Archimedean $\implies$ $\lim_{n
\to \infty} U(f,P_{n})=\int_{0}^{2} f$.

Where is my thinking going wrong?

Comment: And what is the Archimedes-Riemann theorem? What does it mean for a partition to be Archimedian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not asked that $\|P_n\| \to 0$.

Choose $f(x) = x$ and $P_1 = (0,2)\,$, $P_2 = (0,1/4,2)\,$, $P_3 = (0,1/8,1/4,2)\,$, etc.  In this way each partition $P_n$ has $n$ subintervals.

We have $$\lim_{n \to \infty}U(P_n,f) = 2 \cdot (2 - 1/4) + \sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k}\left( \frac{1}{2^k} - \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\right) \\ = \frac{7}{2} + \sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{2k+1}} \\ > 2,$$

which converges, but not to the value $\int_0^2 x \, dx = 2$.